# E-mail sent from within an app - Changing font?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got it working so an e-mail is sent from within my app. The string that make p the body is made up from various aspects of the app screen.

Is there a way to change the font of the text in the body of the e-mail?

Thanks

Comment: That guy already used a custom font for his e-mail body, it just didn't work (probably due to it being a custom font). I just need to know how to change to font in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method :

```
- (void)setMessageBody:(NSString*)body isHTML:(BOOL)isHTML
```

of MFMailComposeViewController class.

In Html you can change the font easily.

Use this as reference :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/setMessageBody:isHTML:

Comment: OK i've got pass HTML. I wasn't sure if that was the only way. Thanks